# SSH tunnel through a Jump Host

Tags: ssh, openvpn

We are using OPENVPN to access our server over private IP with Jump Box. Our architecture is like below it may help us to undertsand the environment:

We are using 5 different subnet and want to access them via openvpn. The subnet are below:

1. 10.110.0.0/20
2. 10.120.0.0/20
3. 10.121.0.0/20
4. 10.130.0.0/20
5. 10.133.0.0/20

our VPN server and Jump Box exist in the 10.133.0.0/20 subnet. Below are the route from my laptop when we are connected with OPENVPN:

```
dagar@dagar:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp1s0
10.133.0.0      172.21.1.1      255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

Below is my `.ssh/config` file configuration:

```
Host 10.139.*.*
  IdentityFile "/home/dagar/.ssh/id_rsa"
  User admin
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p  abc@10.133.27.252 -p 911
  Port 911
Host 10.133.*.*
  IdentityFile "/home/dagar/.ssh/id_rsa"
  User admin
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p  abc@10.133.27.252 -p 911
  Port 911
```

In the above configuration `10.133.27.252` is my Jump Box server IP.

We are able to SSH all subnet server using Jump Box with above configuration except `10.133.0.0/20` subnet servers.

We are able to SSH `10.133.0.0/20` servers directly from user laptop when we comment the `ProxyCommand` from `.ssh/config` file for `10.133.00/20` subnet.

We want to SSH `10.133.0.0/20` subnet machines also via Jump Box.

Can you please help me why its not working for one subnet?

Any help or guidance will be appriciated.

Thank You

Comment: First determine why you "are able to SSH 10.133.0.0/20 servers directly from user laptop". Until you do that, your jump box is providing no extra security.

Comment: @jhnc, We are able to SSH "10.133.0.0/20" servers directly from our laptop because our VPN server exist in "10.133.0.0/20" subnet and we have route for this subnet when user connected with VPN.